# Как поменять местами строки и колонки 2d массива?

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Пытаюсь написать метод для *транспонирования* двухмерного массива `int[][]`, в котором строки и колонки матрицы меняются местами.

Тем не менее, не могу понять, как мне реализовать это? Как мне написать этот метод?

```java
public class Matrix {
    private int[][] numbers;

    public Matrix(int rows, int colums) {
        if (rows < 1)
            rows = 1;
        else
            rows = rows;
        if (colums < 1)
            colums = 1;
        else
            colums = colums;
        numbers = new int[rows][colums];
    }

    public final void setNumbers(int[][] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public int[][] getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public int[][] transpose() {
        int[][] transpose = getNumbers();
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Транспонирование матрицы

```java
int m = 4;
int n = 5;
```

```java
// исходная матрица
int[][] arr1 = {
        {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
        {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24, 25},
        {26, 27, 28, 29, 30}};

// транспонированная матрица
int[][] arr2 = new int[n][m];

// меняем местами строки и колонки
IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.range(0, m).forEach(j ->
                arr2[i][j] = arr1[j][i]));
```

---

```java
// вывод в таблицу markdown
String matrices = Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
        .map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("<br>")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("</pre> | <pre>", "| <pre>", "</pre> |"));

System.out.println("| исходная матрица | транспонированная матрица |");
System.out.println("|---|---|");
System.out.println(matrices);
```

| исходная матрица | транспонированная матрица |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [11, 12, 13, 14, 15] [16, 17, 18, 19, 20] [21, 22, 23, 24, 25] [26, 27, 28, 29, 30] ``` | ``` [11, 16, 21, 26] [12, 17, 22, 27] [13, 18, 23, 28] [14, 19, 24, 29] [15, 20, 25, 30] ``` |

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Зачем менять? Можно просто написать не arr[i][j], а arr[j][i]

**2)** Вот метод

```
private static int[][] getArr(int[][] numbers) {
    int w = numbers[0].length;
    int h = numbers.length;
    int[][] arr = new int[w][h];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            arr[x][y] = numbers[y][x];
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Для проверки:

```
private static void printArr(int[][] arr) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int x = 0; x <  arr.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.print(arr[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы переписал Matrix чуток по другому:

```java
public class Matrix {
    private int columnsNumber;
    private int rowNumber;
    private int[][] numbers;

    public Matrix(int rows, int colums) {
        if (rows < 1)
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid row count");
        if (colums < 1)
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid columns count");
        this.columnsNumber = colums;
        this.rowNumber = rows;
        numbers = new int[this.rowNumber][this.columnsNumber];
    }

    public final void setNumbers(int[][] numbers) {
        if (numbers.length < 1)
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid row count");
        if (numbers[0].length < 1)
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid columns count");

        this.rowNumber = numbers.length;
        this.columnsNumber = numbers[0].length;

        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public int[][] getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public int[][] transpose() {
        int[][] transpose = new int[this.columnsNumber][this.rowNumber];
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < this.rowNumber; rowIndex++)
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < this.columnsNumber; colIndex++)
                transpose[rowIndex][colIndex] =
                        this.numbers[rowIndex][colIndex];
        return transpose;
    }
}
```